# react-native. Reference Error value is not defined

Tags: react-native, reference, bind, setstate

I'm having a problem setting a state in react-native. I can console.log the value just fine but when I call setState() I get Reference error 'targetSpreadsheet' is not defined.

This is in following function

```
getCategories = (file) => {
        console.log(this.state.targetSpreadsheet); // works fine
        this.setState({targetSpreadsheet: file});  // targetSpreadsheet is not defined.
}
```

And a picker that calls it

```
  <SimplePicker
    ref={'picker2'}
    options={this.state.spreadsheetNames}
    onSubmit={(option) => {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.state.spreadsheets.files.length; i++){
        if(this.state.spreadsheets.files[i].name === option){
          let file = this.state.spreadsheets.files[i];
          this.getCategories(file);
          break;
        }
      }
    }}
  />
```

EDIT

constructor

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      targetSpreadsheet: ''
    }

    this.getCategories = this.getCategories.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: I belive that state will be there but provide us show that we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This show you want to access the spreadsheets **object** that has **files array** in it

```
this.state.spreadsheets.files[I]
```

But In your constructor you have initialised `targetSpreadsheet` as and string object, so you are getting error.

```
this.state = {
      targetSpreadsheet: ''
    }
```

**Solution :** You need to make it as an object with files as an empty array.

```
    this.state = {
              targetSpreadsheet: {
                  files:[]
               }
   }
```

Comment: first- thanks.. second- oh no.. As there is no way to know (?) where the error is coming from, it will take years to find the wrong initiation..